# Best way of mapping data from one object to another using a key

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a JSON Object Summary like this

```
[
  {
    "Project": "P1234",
    "Domain": "Domain1",
    "Manager": "Manager1",
    "Milestone":[],
    "Artefacts":[]

  },
  {
    "Project": "P2345",
    "Domain": "Domain2",
    "Manager": "Manager2",
    "Milestone":[],
    "Artefacts":[]
  },
  {
    "Project": "P3277",
    "Domain": "Domain3",
    "Manager": "Manager1",
    "Milestone":[],
    "Artefacts":[]
  }
]
```

And a detailed set like this

```
{
  "Artefacts": [
    {
      "Project": "P1234",
      "ArtefactType": "Art1",
      "Date": "15/10/2021"
    },
    {
      "Project": "P1234",
      "ArtefactType": "Art2",
      "Date": "10/11/2020"
    },
    {
      "Project": "P1234",
      "ArtefactType": "Art3",
      "Date": "5/10/2021"
    },
    {
      "Project": "P2345",
      "ArtefactType": "Art1",
      "Date": "15/10/2021"
    },
    {
      "Project": "P2345",
      "ArtefactType": "Art7",
      "Date": "06/05/2021"
    }
  ],
  "Milestones": [
    {
      "Project": "P1234",
      "Type": "M1",
      "MilestoneDetails": "Details"
    },
    {
      "Project": "P1234",
      "Type": "M2",
      "MilestoneDetails": "Details"
    },
    {
      "Project": "P1234",
      "Type": "M3",
      "MilestoneDetails": "Details"
    },
    {
      "Project": "P2345",
      "Type": "M1",
      "MilestoneDetails": "Details"
    },
    {
      "Project": "P2345",
      "Type": "M2",
      "MilestoneDetails": "Details"
    },
    {
      "Project": "P2345",
      "Type": "M3",
      "MilestoneDetails": "Details"
    },
    {
      "Project": "P3277",
      "Type": "M1",
      "MilestoneDetails": "Details"
    },
    {
      "Project": "P3277",
      "Type": "M2",
      "MilestoneDetails": "Details"
    },
    {
      "Project": "P3277",
      "Type": "M3",
      "MilestoneDetails": "Details"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am getting the Summary and detail from the server in 2 API requests. So I need to MAP the Summary table's Milestone and Artefacts from the detail table using Project Code.

```
this.clSummary.forEach(element=>{
  element.Milestone=this.getMilestones(element.ProjectCode);
  element.Artefacts=this.getArtefacts(element.ProjectCode);
})
```

Is it the good way or any easy or pro way using any arrow functions or linq?

Comment: LINQ is a C# technology, not JS

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are looking for something like this.

```js
summary.forEach((sum) => {
  sum.Artefacts = details.Artefacts.filter(
    ({ Project }) => Project === sum.Project
  );
  sum.Milestone = details.Milestones.filter(
    ({ Project }) => Project === sum.Project
  );
});
```

This returns updates the summary to look like this.

```json
[
  {
    Project: "P1234",
    Domain: "Domain1",
    Manager: "Manager1",
    Artefacts: [
      {
        ArtefactType: "Art1",
        Date: "15/10/2021",
        Project: "P1234",
      },
      {
        ArtefactType: "Art2",
        Date: "10/11/2020",
        Project: "P1234",
      },
      {
        ArtefactType: "Art3",
        Date: "5/10/2021",
        Project: "P1234",
      },
    ],
    
    Milestone: [
      {
        MilestoneDetails: "Details",
        Project: "P1234",
        Type: "M1",
      },
      {
        MilestoneDetails: "Details",
        Project: "P1234",
        Type: "M2",
      },
      {
        MilestoneDetails: "Details",
        Project: "P1234",
        Type: "M3",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    Project: "P2345",
    Domain: "Domain2",
    Manager: "Manager2",
    Artefacts: [
      {
        ArtefactType: "Art1",
        Date: "15/10/2021",
        Project: "P2345",
      },
      {
        ArtefactType: "Art7",
        Date: "06/05/2021",
        Project: "P2345",
      },
    ],
    Milestone: [
      {
        MilestoneDetails: "Details",
        Project: "P2345",
        Type: "M1",
      },
      {
        MilestoneDetails: "Details",
        Project: "P2345",
        Type: "M2",
      },
      {
        MilestoneDetails: "Details",
        Project: "P2345",
        Type: "M3",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    Project: "P3277",
    Artefacts: [],
    Domain: "Domain3",
    Manager: "Manager1",
    Milestone: [
      {
        MilestoneDetails: "Details",
        Project: "P3277",
        Type: "M1",
      },
      {
        MilestoneDetails: "Details",
        Project: "P3277",
        Type: "M2",
      },
      {
        MilestoneDetails: "Details",
        Project: "P3277",
        Type: "M3",
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

Comment: if this solved your answer, please mark it as solved.